# why is there a referencing in front of a method name?

Tags: c++, class, methods, reference, declaration

The last line is my question.  The rest I have included for context. Why there is '&' in front of move?

```
#include <string>

class Screen{
public:
    //friend declarations
    friend class Window_Mgr;

    //type members
    using pos = std::string::size_type;

    //constructors
    Screen() = default;
    Screen( pos h, pos w ) : height( h ), width( w ), contents( h * w, ' ' ){}
    Screen( pos h, pos w, char c ) : height( h ), width( w ), contents( h * w, c ){}

    //methods
    char Get() const { return contents[ cursor ]; }
    char Get( pos, pos ) const;
    Screen &Move( pos, pos );
```

Comment: Read it as `Screen& Move( pos, pos );` instead. The `&` is part of the return type, the function returns a reference.

Comment: `Screen &Move( pos, pos );` is same as `Screen& Move( pos, pos );`. just style differs.

Comment: You mean the function returns a reference to a Screen object?

Comment: @HannuHell: Yes, exactly.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why `Move()` would be returning `Screen&`, but it could be for [method chaining](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#method-chaining).

Answer (score 0):

see that as this:
you can declare a pointer like:

```
int* myIntP;
```

OR

```
int *myIntP;
```

well, same is valid for methods:

```
 Screen &Move( pos, pos );
```

is the equivalent to

```
 Screen& Move( pos, pos );
```